# How to consume a Windows DLL method

Tags: windows, go

I am trying to use the [`GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158(v=vs.85).aspx) method which is present in kernel32.dll.

It requires a single argument of the type [PULONGLONG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#PULONGLONG), but I have no idea how to map this into a golang variable. Here is my current attempt which results in "err: The parameter is incorrect".

Can anyone explain how to do this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

var memory uintptr

func main() {
    kernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    getPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemoryProc := kernel32.NewProc("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory")

    ret, _, err := getPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemoryProc.Call(uintptr(memory))
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, return: %+v\n", ret)
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, memory: %d\n", memory)
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, err: %s\n", err)

}
```

Comment: its helpful if you can leave a comment explaining reason for down vote - I will probably do the same again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `PULONGLONG` parameter type translates to `*uint64`
2. You must cast the the address of the `memory` variable to the [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) type and then to `uintptr`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    kernel32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    getPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemoryProc := kernel32.NewProc("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory")

    var memory uint64

    ret, _, err := getPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemoryProc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&memory)))
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, return: %+v\n", ret)
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, memory: %d\n", memory)
    fmt.Printf("GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory, err: %s\n", err)

}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim - I had something similar at one point without the unsafe pointer, I think I get it now but still struggling to get how to do this for all types, looking at how I would reference a class now - I don't suppose you know of any good tutorials around c/go bindings